# MobaXterm use ssh passwords for server authentification

Tags: windows, mobaxterm

I want to create a MobaXterm user session to access a server via ssh.
I use a username and password for authentication. The option using the ssh key is unfortunately not available to me.
Furthermore, access to the server takes place via a jump server which is also protected with a username and password.

Under "Settings > Configuration > MobaXterm passwords management" I enabled "save ssh keys passphrases as well" and set "ask" for saving session passwords.

In the credentials section I created both credentials for accessing the servers with the requested username, password and as name the ip addr of the server.

How can I configure my user session to use these credentials to connect to the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to a server using SSH Key in MobaXterm, you can try the following steps:

1. Select Private Key
   (1) Check the box for "Use private key" in the connection settings.
   (2) Click the blue file button on the right side of the input box.
   (3) Choose the private key file in the popup window.
2. Configure Username and Private Key Passphrases (If not specified, you'll need to set this every time you connect, which can be cumbersome.)
   (1) Check "Specify username."
   (2) Click the user config button on the right side of the input box.
   (3) (If the private key has a passphrase) Check "Save SSH keys passphrases as well."
   (4) Click on "New"
   (5) Fill in the user settings and click "OK" to save. (If there is no private key passphrase, you can leave the password field blank for this)
3. Select the Configured User
4. Go back to the initial interface, select the configured user, and click "OK" to save.
5. Connect Again

You can now connect again to log in to the server.